# How to extract and synchronize the list of packages pre-installed in Colab?

Tags: conda, google-colaboratory

I want to build a conda environment on my own server with the same packages in Colab. Moreover, can I also synchronize the package version on Colab so that everything is updated and compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at pip-freeze.txt file (for `pip install`) and apt-list.txt (for `apt install`) here

https://github.com/googlecolab/backend-info